# Extracting all possible constituent subsets of a larger set

Tags: r, list, combinations

I've been struggling with this problem for a day or so, so I thought I would ask your help. I thought I was close to a solution, but I'm not as close as I hoped, and I'm working on a deadline so would love some guidance.

I'm trying to extract all possible combinations of subsets from a larger set.

Say that our original set contains the elements (A,B,C). I want to write a function which returns these combinations of subsets:

1 - (A),(B),(C)

2 - (A),(B and C)

3 - (B),(A and C)

4 - (C),(A and B)

Order doesn't matter to me; i.e., (C),(A and B) is not any different from 
(C),(B and A).

By my count, this is all there are for the original set, but of course it rapidly gets out of hand as you increase the number of elements. I am trying to apply it to a vector with 17 distinct elements.

In my head the preferred R output would look something like this, but I'm not particularly wedded to a list of lists, if there is a better way of returning output that conveys the same information (i.e., of distinguishing instances in which individual elements are grouped into subsets with other elements from instances in which they are their own subset). I'm sure there is, this is just the mess I had worked myself into working on my own solution.

```
originalvector<-c(A,B,C)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] A B C

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] A

[[2]]
[[2]][[2]]
[2] B C

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] B

[[3]]
[[3]][[2]]
[2] A C

[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] C

[[4]]
[[4]][[2]]
[1] A B
```

Note: I know that there are various posts about extracting possible permutations/combinations, but I wasn't able to find one that helped me enough to solve this problem.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter,  `lapply(1:3, function(x) combn(v1,x, FUN=list))` where `v1 <- LETTERS[1:3]`

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, this problem scales with the so-called Bell number (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). And B(17)=83 * 10^9. Are you sure you can handle this?

Comment: ... if so, look at `setparts`.

Comment: Thanks to you both. @akrun unless I have made a mistake that isn't exactly what I was after, but it's very neat code. Everything I had done in loops wrapped up into lapply. @cyro111 it is indeed that same problem, and, no, I am not sure I can handle it! But `setparts` is a very helpful start, thanks for the tip